# How to show point icon on image at specific point in <img> tag in html5 like google maps

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

we have an image tag and when the user clicks at a specific point on the image , i want to show a point icon at that position like the google maps is showing on the maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for instance do something like this:

**Javascript**

```
var $clickable = $('#clickable');
$clickable.on('click', function(e) {
  var $pointer;
  $clickable.append('<div class="pointer" />');
  $pointer = $clickable.find('.pointer');
  $pointer.css({
    top: event.pageY - $clickable.offset().top,
    left: event.pageX - $clickable.offset().left
  })
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

Please take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/xonqq259/1/ for a working example.

You need a relative wrapper and add a pointer element with absolute positioning.